# Add secondary menu that dose not collapse on small screens in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I want to add a login link in primary nav, but I don't want it to collapse on small screen. It should appear besides logo.
Can anyone help?

I tried to create secondary navigation but I am unable to show it on primary navigation location, as main navigation disappears. Means I cannot show 2 navigation on same location.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS/JavaScript/jQuery to get the login link from the primary nav and display/move it the way you want on mobile. Without any code or image of your project it's hard to give a more precise answer.

Comment: here is how I achieved it.

I did it by registering another nav 1) In functions.php i wrote function menu_besides_logo() { register_nav_menu('new_menu', __('Menue Besides Logo')); } add_action('init','menu_besides_logo' ); 2) In Appearance->Menu assign a menu 3) in header.php wp_nav_menu (array ( 'theme_location' => 'new_menu')); 4) show/hide above menu via CSS using media queries. –

Comment: Glad you could solve it. This it's a good way if you want to keep the links in 2 different menus.